# Change dd-mm-yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have some data in MS excel where there are dates mentioned in a column in 2 different formats(**dd-mm-yyyy** & **mm/dd/yyyy**). How do I make them similar or convert them to **mm/dd/yyyy** format?

Comment: question is: are they real dates with different formatting ? or just strings representing a date ?

Comment: Are they all right-aligned or left-aligned? Are some right-aligned and some left-aligned? What is your system's regional setting? DMY or MDY?

Comment: I guess they are strings. If not how to identify so?

Comment: well some of them are left aligned and some are right aligned. The regional setting is DMY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select the dropdown you would normally select to format the column to a date. Then select the custom option to specify your own formula for the format.

Comment: can you share some sort of visuals? Actually I am new to it @Harriet

Comment: im not ay a pc with excel at the moment...

Comment: Hello @Abhishek - I sincerely hope you have this sorted, but in case you did not:  you select the column you want to work with, and you right click and select format cells. Then a dialog will open that will allow you to make changes to the formatting. If you do not find the formatting you are interested in in the Date dialog, then you select Custom, and enter the formula yourself. I hope this helps, if not too late...